# Did the update to Puzzle Swap which added Kid Icarus also add any other puzzles?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, puzzle-swap

I was just wondering if any additional puzzles were added that weren't revealed yet, or if Kid Icarus was the only one. I'd rather not know what they are though, just a yes and how many or no. Thanks!
(I also think its really cool they've started distributing puzzles through the internet, I hope they do more this way!)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a particular good question. Right now the answer is "no" afaik; at some point in the (near? probably, Luigi's Mansion) future it's going to become "yes" in a rather obvious way, and then it's going to stay "yes" forever.

Comment: I'm VTC your question as "Too Localized" since the current list of revealed puzzles will change drastically overtime. this also seems to be asking about if there are any plans to release additional content in the future, which is considered speculation of the industry which is off-topic as outlined in our [FAQ]

Answer (score 3):

There have been many claims that there are more puzzles in that update (Nintendo mentioned that there were more to unlock at some point, more than just Kid Icarus), but there has been no real proof anywhere that they added more than that puzzle.

Considering how long it has been since the update, and that there have been no reports of an added puzzle that was not Kid Icarus, I think it is safe to say that that was the last puzzle to be added, and there have not (as of April 2012) been any more added.

Answer (score 0):

After Kid Icarus: Uprising the next puzzle is Mario Tennis Open which brings the total number of puzzles to 16 and the number of puzzle pieces to 385 .... and just when i thought I was almost finished  O_o

Comment: When was that added? Do you have any official word that it is added?

Comment: @DerpyHooves: [A piece arrived via SpotPass yesterday](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2012/04/new_puzzle_panel_lands_via_spotpass), same as when they added the Kid Icarus puzzle. Maybe it's only Europe so far?

Answer (score -2):

No thats the only one it added.

Comment: not very true. They added Mario Tennis Open.